# Rounded button in ASP.NET using css not working in IE

Tags: asp.net, css

I am using the following style for an ASP.NET button. It is working in Chrome, but I am not getting the rounded corners in IE. How to fix this?

```
.button 
{
   -moz-border-radius: 20px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
   -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color:white;
    background-color: #BD90DE; 
}
```

Comment: Its not going to work, you need to cut the edges and then place them in css after that assign that class to button it start showing rounded button to you.

Comment: Check these links http://hribar.info/en/archive/81/entrie.html and http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/html-and-css-rounded-corner-button-generator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE<9 does not support rounded corners.
You can use [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) or other libraries to fake them.

Answer (score 3):

Border-radius only works in IE9.

Also, it will only work if quirks mode is not on. Press F12 to open the developers windows, and check at the top that Browser Mode and Document mode are set to IE9.